# Как записать в OutputStream только четные индексы?

Tags: java

Встал на Вводе/Выводе поток байт. Нужно написать метод, который принимает InputStream и OutputStream, считывает все байты из inputStream и записывает в OutputStream только четные индексы.Что только не перепробовал...В чем ошибка? Или прочитать inputStream - вычислить количество четных элементов и создать новый массив из новой длины и записать в OutputStream? Помогите, плз)

```
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int i;
while ((i = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
    if (inputStream.read(buf) != 0) {
        if ((i % 2) == 0) {
            outputStream.write(buf, 0, i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: вы считываете вроде правильно, а вот записываете вы что то не то

Comment: Вот я и не могу понять что :( Если четные числа искать в inputStream и записывать в outputStream, то выдает все верно...

Comment: Я решил задачу путем проверки байта на четность)

Comment: С первого взгляда: во-первых Вы во write не меняете смещение, во-вторых проверяете на чётность не индекс, а содержимое потока.